# How to setup Linpack xtreme input parameters

Tags: benchmarking, linpack

I was setting up some benchmark and i need to use this benchmark tool to test my ryzen cpu and then compare results. As a request i need to test it under different number of equations. I think that there should be a lininput file to setup this parameters, but it doesn't appear in the rar i downloaded.  How can i set the input parameter N?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It will be present in a file called "settings" in the extracted directory